# VSTO addin (2003-2007) Ms Word & Webservices

Tags: ms-word, vsto

I am planning on starting my 1st VSTO project.

What I want to be able to do is:

- Download and Upload versions of a MS
  Word document to a web service. With
  authentication by overriding the save
  button
- Call a web service to list a bunch of tag that can be inserted into a document.  When a user double clicks a tag the selected tag is inserted into the cursor position.

I am pretty sure this is all possible just want some confirmation?  Also would like to know how long would it take to make something like this. I think the biggest issue will be authentication and listing exiting files to download then allowing the user to download a .doc and restore previous versions of that file via the web service.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, don't see any reason any of that wouldn't be doable. With a VSTO addin, you can pretty much fully control word, unload docs, load docs, save them whereever, etc. Authentication, and webservice handling is completely separate from vsto. But it can all live within the VSTO addin.